# Microsoft NuGet packages release notes

Tags: c#, nuget

Is it possible to see some sort of release notes/version history for the Microsoft NuGet packages?

As an example, we currently have version 1.0.5 of *Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform* installed in our solution, and now there's an update available to version 1.0.6 
(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform).

This is a potentially important update as it involves the Roslyn compiler used to compile our web app. Obviously release notes should be distributed, as it helps with the following issues:

- How should this update be prioritized (in terms of project management)
- What should be tested after we apply this update
- Does it solve any of the existing known issues in our app

I suspect that it involves the Roslyn project (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), but I'm unable to find any usable release notes there.

Comment: I doubt release notes or a change log are available.

Comment: ive just taken a look on nuget, and via VS and done see the release notes

Comment: @nnn, This is an old issue, but as a general case might still be useful to others. Please consider marking an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2):

If the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` did have release notes, they would most likely be in the `<releaseNotes>` element within the .nuspec file for the package. Installing version 1.0.6 and unzipping its .nupkg file, I found this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform</id>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <title>CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn")</title>
    <authors>Microsoft</authors>
    <owners>Microsoft</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <licenseUrl>http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_ENU.htm</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://www.asp.net/</projectUrl>
    <description>Replacement CodeDOM providers that use the new .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") compiler as a service APIs. This provides support for new language features in systems using CodeDOM (e.g. ASP.NET runtime compilation) as well as improving the compilation performance of these systems.</description>
    <summary>Replacement CodeDOM providers that use the new .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") compiler as a service APIs.</summary>
    <copyright>© Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.</copyright>
    <language>en-US</language>
    <tags>Roslyn CodeDOM Compiler CSharp VB.Net ASP.NET</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.3.2" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6">
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="2.1.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
    <iconUrl>http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=288859</iconUrl>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

It doesn't look like there are any release notes here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9483) under roslyn repository, given package is NOT handled by Roslyn team:

> jaredpar commented on May 30 2017
>
> @niemyjski note that despite the name we don't own this particular package.
> It's produced by the ASP.net team. The repo for the package is here
> https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider

And that repo does seem to contain code to build the package and something similar to release notes can be found here:

https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/releases

Which state for 1.0.6:

> Fixing issue#2 & issue#10
>
> Adding support for custom location of Roslyn binaries

The issues are:

- [Fail to copy Roslyn compiler bits to the right location on build server #2](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/2)
- ["Access to path denied" error #10](https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/10)